# Handling decimal values in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, formatting, apache-spark-sql

I have data in a file as shown below:

```
7373743343333444.
7373743343333432.
```

This data should be converted to decimal values and should be in a position of 8.7 where 8 are the digits before decimal and 7 are the digits after decimal.
I am trying to read the data file as below:

```
val readDataFile = Initialize.spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").schema(***SCHEMA*****).load(****DATA FILE PATH******)
```

I have tried this:

```
val changed = dataFileWithSchema.withColumn("COLUMN NAME", dataFileWithSchema.col("COLUMN NAME").cast(new DecimalType(38,3)))
println(changed.show(5))
```

but it only gives me zeros at the end of the number, like this:

```
7373743343333444.0000
```

But I want the digits formatted as described above, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is a problem - you have number `7373743343333444.` and it is same as `7373743343333444.0000`?

Comment: You have 16 characters long numbers in the example but want it to be 8.7, should the last digit be removed?

Answer (score 0):

A simple combination of `regexp_replace`, `trim` and `format_number` inbuilt function should get you what you desire

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("column", regexp_replace(format_number(trim(regexp_replace(col("column"), "\\.", "")).cast("long")/100000000, 7), ",", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide the column by `10^8`, this will move the decimal point 8 steps. After that cast to `DecimalType` to get the correct number of decimals. Since there are 16 digits to begin with, this means the last one is removed.

```
df.withColumn("col", (col("col").cast(DoubleType)/math.pow(10,8)).cast(DecimalType(38,7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df
.withColumn("newValue", expr("cast( cast(id as long) / pow(10, 8) as decimal(38, 7))"))
.show(false)
```

```
+-----------------+----------------+
|id               |newValue        |
+-----------------+----------------+
|7373743343333444.|73737433.4333344|
|7373743343333432.|73737433.4333343|
+-----------------+----------------+
```